# javascript - how to get the inner html width of the webpage

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a few client sites that have a width of about 900px-1000px centered, using javascript how can I find out what the actual width of the document is? I don't need to know the width of the window, just the width that the actual html document is using.

I also can't use any div id's to find it. I know I can use jquery for this, but I'd like to use plain javascript as jquery isn't running on all the sites.

In jquery, I can find this out by using:

```
$('body').outerWidth(true)
```

Can someone help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var body = document.getElementsByTag("body")[0];
var width = body.style.width;
```

another option:

```
var body = document.getElementsByTag("body")[0];
var width = body.offsetWidth;
```

Answer (score 0):

To find width of a document use:

```
    $(document).width();
```